# Java first attempt on simple calculator (what's happened?)

Tags: java, console, calculator

Main.java (Main Class)

```
package com.indie;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static com.indie.Operations.*;

public class Main {
    private static double Number1;
    private static double Number2;
    private static double Total;
    private static String Symbol;
    private static boolean noError;
    private static boolean exceptioncaught;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        noError = false;
        while (!noError) {
            exceptioncaught = false;
            while (!exceptioncaught) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter your number:");
                try {
                    Number1 = scanner.nextDouble();
                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("TypeERROR: You didn't input a vaild number!");
                    exceptioncaught = true;
                    System.out.println();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    break;
                }
             System.out.println("What do you want to do:");
            Symbol = scanner.next();
            if (!Symbol.contains("+") && !Symbol.contains("-") && !Symbol.contains("*") && !Symbol.contains("x") && !Symbol.contains("/") && !Symbol.contains("÷")) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("TypeERROR: You didn't input a valid symbol!");
                exceptioncaught = true;
                System.out.println();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                break;
                }
                System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                try {
                    Number1 = scanner.nextDouble();
                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("TypeERROR: You didn't input a vaild number!");
                    exceptioncaught = true;
                    System.out.println();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println();
                if (Symbol.contains("+")) {
                    Total = Add(Number1, Number2);
                    noError = true;
                    break;
                } else if (Symbol.contains("-")) {
                    Total = Subtract(Number1, Number2);
                    noError = true;
                    break;
                } else if (Symbol.contains("*") || Symbol.contains("x")) {
                    Total = Multiply(Number1, Number2);
                    noError = true;
                    break;
                } else if (Symbol.contains("/") || Symbol.contains("÷")) {
                    Total = Divide(Number1, Number2);
                    noError = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(Number1)
                           +Symbol+String.valueOf(Number2) 
                           +"="+String.valueOf(Total));
    }
}
```

Operations.java (2nd Class)

```
package com.indie;

public class Operations {
    public static double Add(double x, double y) { return x+y; }
    public static double Subtract(double x, double y){ return x-y; }
    public static double Multiply(double x, double y){ return x*y; }
    public static double Divide(double x, double y){ return x/y; }
}
```

[Got this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJGeX.png)

Any way of fixing it? How did it end up with 2.0+20.0=2.0? Please Help.
Any way of preventing it from giving that type of results?

> Other results:
>
> result 1:
>
> Enter your number:
>
> 2
>
> What do you want to do:
>
> +5
>
> Enter your second number:
>
> 56
>
> 56.0+50.0=56.0
>
> result 2:
>
> Enter your number:
>
> 1
>
> What do you want to do:
>
> +1
>
> Enter your second number:
>
> 1
>
> 1.0+10.0=1.0

Comment: You should spend some time debugging your homework. It's ok to struggle a bit.

Comment: `"Enter your number:"` followed by `Number1 = scanner.nextDouble();` and `"Enter your second number:"` followed by `Number1 = scanner.nextDouble();` should be a pretty obvious typo error that you should have been able to spot yourself. Although it might not be the only one.

Comment: I know this is not question-related, but Java engineer use lower camel case variable names

Comment: code review stack exchange might help you https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this part of the code, you should change this:

```
...
System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
try {
    Number1 = scanner.nextDouble();
}
...
```

to this:

```
...
System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
try {
    Number2 = scanner.nextDouble();
}
...
```

You never change the value of `Number2` in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've changed that but i still seem to be getting weird results if the symbol variable contains a number after the actual inputted operator... anyway of fixing that?

Comment: You need to limit your input such that only symbols can be entered instead of a numeric string

Answer (score 0):

Something it is goood to have a second pair of eyes
In your code you never assign value to Number2

```
System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
try {
     Number2 = scanner.nextDouble();
```